# Where do I store text files for Python

Tags: python, file

Which folder location do I store text files on my computer for python to access? I'm trying to open a file called word.txt with the command fin = open('words.txt').

Comment: in *nix-like, current directory. or use `os.chdir()`

Comment: You can store them anywhere you have privileges!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the full path to the file.

```
with open('/path/to/words.txt', 'r') as handle:
    print handle.read()
```

Otherwise, it will be using your current directory.

```
import os
# Print your current directory
print os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
```